# IFrame same origin policy vaiolation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to load an iframe in url example.com/somefile.html from a subdomain sub.example.com/dir/frame.html.

Inorder to avoid SOP violation, im setting the document.domain attriute to example.com in javascript code, in both frame.html & somefile.html.

This works in IE and Firefox but I still encounter the following error in Chrome:
"Refused to display "frame-url" in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

When debugging and checking both files document.domain value I get the expected "example.com".

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Answer (score 0):

`document.domain` hacks simply have no effect on `X-Frame-Options` rules. If you want to allow the page to be displayed in a frame then you need to change the `X-Frame-Options` rules.

Use `ALLOW-FROM` instead of `SAMEORIGIN`. The [spec has guidance](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034#page-8) in case you want to allow multiple subdomains access.

Comment: I know your suggestion is the "correct" one, but I have read in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options that ALLOW_FROM isn't supported in Chrome browser.